# Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: NPE

Tags: angular, cordova

I was trying to debug Cordova mobile build in VS Code while building it throws the following the error

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\novaspectapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
'cordova.cmd run android --device --verbose --no-update-notifier' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove node module and install again

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/npm/npm-how-to-reinstall-node-modules-packages/

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

then

```
cordova platform rm android 
cordova platform add android
```